# How i can test this custom react hook

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export function useTabs(initialState: string[]) {
  const [tabs] = useState(initialState);
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

  return {
    tabs,
    activeTab,
    setActiveTab,
  };
}
```

I try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import PaymentMethods from '../index';

const mockedSetState = jest.fn();

describe('test PaymentMethods component', () => {
  jest.mock('../../../hooks/useTabs', () => ({
    useTabs: () => ({
      tabs: ['Полная оплата', 'В кредит', 'Подписка'],
      activeTab: 0,
      setActiveTab: mockedSetState,
    }),
  }));

  it('call mocked set state', () => {
    expect(mockedSetState).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
  });

  it('should render PaymentMethods component', () => {
    expect(shallow(<PaymentMethods />)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

but i have errors:

1. expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
   Expected: 1
   Number of calls: 0
2. test PaymentMethods component › should render PaymentMethods component
   TypeError: useTabs_1.useTabs is not a function

Comment: How did you invoke `setActiveTab` function? Show the code under test